# Combining map with zip through lambda

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function for adding 2D vectors. 
I'm trying to combine the `map()` function, getting a list using the `zip()` function (which will zip 2 tuples).

This is the code:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
c = list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, list(zip(a, b))))
print(c)
```

So the way I see it, `zip(a, b)` returns a zip object containing the following tuples: (1, 3), (2, 4). It is then converted to a list. I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

So my guess is that the lambda function is not taking the second number in each tuple.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one parameter for lambda like:

```
c = list(map(lambda x: sum(x), zip(a, b)))
```

But once we are using sum, we can map it directly like:

```
c = list(map(sum, zip(a, b)))
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
c = list(map(sum, zip(a, b)))
print(c)
```

#### Result:

```
[4, 6]
```

Comment: @abdul_niyas_pm: I suppose it's because the author uses Python 3, where `map` returns a generator (like python 2's `itertools.imap`).

Answer (score 5):

`zip` returns a tuples, so you could sum like this example:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], zip(a, b)))
```

output:

```
[4, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python2, you can use specific unpacking syntax in a `lambda`:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
c = list(map(lambda (x, y): x+y, list(zip(a, b))))
```

However, in Python3, you will have to use `sum`:

```
c = list(map(lambda x_y: sum(x_y), list(zip(a, b))))
```

Comment: So if I wanted to perform some other calculation (one that is short enough for a lambda, but has no internal function such as sum), I'd have to either use the touple indexes or pass an external function to map() ?

Comment: @fishamit `sum` is a builtin function in Python. It will always be available by implementation. However, depending on your version of Python, you can use the tuple unpacking method, predefined function (such as `sum`), or a `lambda`.

Answer (score 3):

The `lambda` receives *one* parameter, which is a 2-tuple returned by `zip`.

- You can access it element-wise: `lambda pair: pair[0] + pair[1]`.
- You can apply `sum()` to it.
- In Python 2, you can unpack it right in the signature: `lambda (x, y): x + y`.